# jQuery filter table includes <select> <option> cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, filter, html-table

I am new to jQuery.
I have a table which contains `<select><option>` tag in a cell like below.

```
<html>
<input type="text" id="searchInput">
<table border=1>
 <thead>
  <th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>position</th>
 </thead>
 <tbody id="fbody">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td><select>
        <option selected>front</option>
        <option>center</option>
        <option>back</option>
        </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td><select>
        <option>front</option>
        <option selected>center</option>
        <option>back</option>
        </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</html>
```

I found a jQuery code like below and I am trying to filter above table. But it won't work good on `<select><option>` cell. I would like to know how I can make code work to filter to get selected value.

What I want to do is, when I type "center" in the input box, then show only second row.

```
<script>
$("#searchInput").keyup(function () {
    console.log("value=%o", this.value);
    //split the current value of searchInput
    var data = this.value.split(" ");
    //create a jquery object of the rows
    var jo = $("#fbody").find("tr")
    //hide all the rows
    .hide();

    //Recusively filter the jquery object to get results.
    jo.filter(function (i, v) {
        var $t = $(this);
        for (var d = 0; d < data.length; ++d) {
            if ($t.is(":contains('" + data[d] + "')")) {
                console.log(data[d]);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    })
    //show the rows that match.
    .show();
}).focus(function () {
    this.value = "";
    $(this).css({
        "color": "black"
    });
    $(this).unbind('focus');
}).css({
    "color": "#C0C0C0"
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try changing your filter condition to

```
jo.each(function () {

    $( this ).find( "td select option:selected" ).each( function(){
        for (var d = 0; d < data.length; ++d) 
        {
            if ( $( this ).text() == data[d] ) 
            {
                console.log(data[d]);
                $( this ).parent("tr").show();
                break;
            }
        }
    })
});
```

or even simply

```
$("#fbody").find("option:selected").each(function () {
   if ( data.indexOf( $( this ).text() ) != -1 ) //updated this line
   {
       $( this ).parent().parent().parent().show();
   }
});
```

if you want to compare part of the value in TDs to the value entered in textboxes

```
  $( data ).each( function ( index, valueArr ){
    if ( value.indexOf( valueArr ) != -1 )
    {
       $td.parent().show();
    }
  } );
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried both of your code, but it doesn't seem working. I put some words in the box, nothing shown.

Comment: @sean_y24 can you please share the fiddle. Just need to verify how you have used the code I have given.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Im new to fiddle too. Let me share the link. I hope this link is the right one. https://jsfiddle.net/0ynqouLL/1/embedded/result/

Comment: @sean_y24 there is a bracket missing, editing the post.

Comment: Thank you! I saw it was working. Can it be working like if I type "B" in the textbox then it will show row2 and also, if I type "ce" it shows row2 too. Thanks, a lot.

Comment: @sean_y24 so you want to show row 2 if 'ce' is typed. Does it mean you want to show the row if the typed value is part of (not exact match) the selected value?

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)  I meant exactly what you said. The word "center"(which is in option) contains "ce" so, if I type "ce" in the box, I want the filter to hit the word "center" .

Answer (score 0):

try to use `:selected`

```
if ($t.find('> select > option').is(":selected:contains('" + data[d] + "')")) {
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I changed my code "if ($t.is(":contains('" + data[d] + "')")) {" to yours, but did not work... Am I changing right place?